# Fast variable insertion into string

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Is there any Intellij Idea hotkey or a plugin to quickly insert variable into string?
e.g. i have string

```
"My code is working, yay! Result is = ",
```

and i have to add construction `"+variable +"`, resulting in

```
"My code is working, yay! Result is = "+ variable +"."
```

to properly insert a variable.

When i have to insert variables into 20+ string, its driving me nuts :)

tried to find solution on google or plugin repository, no result

PS: i know about soutv hotkey, but it cant help me since i have to change already existing strings in code

Comment: Not specific enough. Why don't you make your own live template or use multi caret? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html

Comment: if all the inserted variables are the same, or all different, use multi-carets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added Live Template

```
Abbreviation: ++
Description: Insert variable into string
Expand with: Enter
Template text: "+ $EXPR$ +" (do not forget double quotes)
Edit Template Variable: 
expression:variableOfType("") default Value: "expr"
```

[settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1tjN.jpg)

You type ++ in a string, press Enter, and template text is added, and you only need to choose a variable. Works like a charm.

Thanks for the idea, @Meo